# How do I calculate Earth's velocity?

Tags: orbital-motion, velocity, planets

How do I calculate Earth's velocity (on its elliptical orbital path, as a function)? I know how to calculate it assuming that Earth's orbital path is circular but I want to know what we would do if we take its actual path which is elliptical... I was wondering if Kepler's law of areas would contribute to this?

Comment: Start with its orbit if it was circular. Now note that it is closer to the sun at times and further away at times then it is circular configuration. You can calculate what the difference it gravitational potential energy from the circlular path to the eliptical path at any point. This translates to an equal change in the earths kinetic energy i.e. speed

Comment: Kepler's law does help. $dA =.5rds$ the area of a triangle. And Kepler's law gives $dA/dt=k$ for some constant k. So $v=ds/dt=2k/r$.

Comment: As a function of what? Distance from the Sun? Time?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is the [Vis-viva equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vis-viva_equation).

$$v^2 = GM\left(\frac2r-\frac1a\right)$$

$v$ is the relative speed of the two bodies
$r$ is the distance between the two bodies
$a$ is the length of the semi-major axis ($a > 0$ for ellipses, $a = \infty$ or $1/a = 0$ for parabolas, and $a < 0$ for hyperbolas)
$G$ is the gravitational constant
$M$ is the mass of the central body

Comment: This of course gives the speed, not the velocity.